# Orange with MySQL data import

Tags: python, mysql, orange

I've got data in a MySQL DB and would like to get it into Orange.
So I install Orange 2.7, starting orange-canvas and how would I go on now?

There are Add-Ons for MySQL:
https://github.com/biolab/orange/tree/master/Orange/orng
but how are they being installed? (and where?)
And if installed - how can I connect them to a Data Table component?

Answer (score 0):

These are not add-ons but modules you already have. See documentation http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.data.sql.html

If you want to access SQL from canvas, open Preferences / Categories and enable Prototypes. This will add a new widget category with a lot of weird experimental stuff. There are two different widgets for fetching data from SQL.

Orange 3 (still very much in beta, though) has a much better support for DB, but for now only for Postgres. If you don't mind switching, you should check it.

Comment: Yes - was quite happy to see it working via the Prototypes - connected to MySQL and UTF-8 is working - but unfortunately here, I've got the , problem again: 0,25 turns into 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have used is as follows:
1. php code to query mysql database, and create a tab de-limited file (outside of Orange)
2. python script in Orange, using pandas to load the data.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to answer your second question, "How are Add-Ons being installed?", in respect to the first one, for Orange3 (assuming that you upgraded in the meantime):

Orange3 is distributed with its own Python framework, including the `pip` binary (a package installer, "pip installs packages").

The Orange3 docs [1] tell us which python module to take: `pymssql`.

In my case, on MacOS, the installation path is `/Applications/Orange3.app/`.

So,

- let's open a terminal
- and execute this command:

  ```sh
  /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip install pymssql
  ```
- actually and practically, we had to do this:

  ```sh
  /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip install Cython
  /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip install "pymssql<3.0"
  ```
- then start Orange3 and you should be fine.

HT still H

[1] https://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/widgets/data/sqltable.html

Answer (score -1):

`conda install pymssql` worked for me, it enabled "SQL Server" in SQL Table configuration, however I have not been able to get mysql connector working yet.